# Do people really care about handshakes? Is there statistics on it?

Tags: greetings

We're often told that a good handshake is important and makes for a strong first-impression.

Personally, I don't think a handshake says anything about a person, other than the fact that they have a hand. And I can't imagine what sort of person would really put much weight into that. I mean, whether your handshake is firm or loose, short or long, two-handed or single-handed, still or shaky ... *who the hell cares*?

That's not a rhetorical question, that's my actual question. **Who cares**? Is there some data on this phenomenon, i.e. how many people care about handshakes, what sort of people they are (i.e., are they old or young, employers or employees, Italians or Americans, etc) and if so, what particular type of handshake do they prefer?

Comment: This is extremely dependent upon the culture of the people involved. Can you please [edit] this to specify the culture you are asking about?

Comment: @sphennings to me it looks like that if the OP would have to limit their question to a single culture, there would be hardly any answer. They're asking about **data** (so academic work, not many sources available) on **handshakes** (so a sigle gesture). It'd add value to this question to have a comparison of handshakes in different cultures.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the close reason. Someone might well be able to give a clear and concise answer to this question: studies have found that X% of Americans think a firm handshake is important versus Y% of Britons and Z% of Germans, or whatever data they are able to find. I'm sure someone could write a book on the history and meaning and beat the subject to death, but you could say that about almost any question on here.

Answer (score 5):

After some research, I found some interesting links that might provide some answers to your question:

- [More than a Handshake - BBC](http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20130809-more-than-a-handshake)

The article shows the traditions for greetings, schedules, meetings, and meals for countries around the world- here is the U.S. for example.

> "In the United States...
>
> Greetings: People introduce themselves by name and with a firm handshake to everyone present. Business culture in the US is generally mindful of the separation between professional and private life. While pleasantries and a brief exchange asking how someone is doing are common, conversation quickly moves to business. Similarly, Americans are very conscious about personal space and tend to give more than in European or Latin countries. Close-talking is generally uncomfortable in American professional settings.
>
> Schedules: Whether on phone calls, to meals or dinner, promptness is expected. Many people in the US consider being on time as actually being late in business settings, so be sure to arrive early. That said, expect a straggler or two. Business dinners generally follow the conclusion of the workday and tend to start as late as 19:00.
>
> Meetings: In most business settings, Americans schedule meeting times and stick to them. Conversation is usually kept on-topic and sticks to business, with light conversation before or after a meeting wraps. While it varies by industry, Americans tend to dress conservatively, although many workplaces in the US have adopted business casual dress policies.
>
> Meals: Americans are open to scheduling and doing business at any meal, including breakfast. But people watch the clock, including during business lunches, which are typically kept to one-hour’s time. Don’t be put off by your host checking his or her watch at regular intervals, but answering calls or checking phones during a meal is impolite. Wait until everyone is served before eating. Americans are known to be big eaters, so feel free to take seconds if offered. Keep in mind that smoking is unpopular indoors the US, not to mention illegal in most settings where a business meal would take place. To be safe (and avoid potential judgment) wait until the meal has concluded to smoke outside. Follow the host’s lead when it comes to ordering alcohol."

- [What proper handshake etiquette is around the world - Mental Floss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/54063/what-proper-handshake-etiquette-around-world)

The article talks about each country's type of greeting, and if it includes an handshake or not.

> "Brazil
> Expect a firm handshake that lasts longer than you’re used to. Mix in strong eye contact, and greet women with a kiss on each cheek. Repeat when you leave."

If you don't mind a longer read, I found a research paper.

- [Handshaking, Gender, Personality, and First Impressions - Chaplin et al 2000](https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/psp791110.pdf)

TL;DR Each country has different cultures and meanings behind handshakes, or whether they use one at all, and the research effort is too vast for me to put into one long answer here. These links provide a good start to exploring the statistics for handshakes and their use globally.